# jquery betterTooltip w/Awesomeness - tool tip not displaying in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

If you visit this link: http://pearlofthewest.com/ and view the page using chrome or firefox, the betterTooltip image/text shows up when hovering above an image in the slideviewer. In Safari, the betterTooltip shows up, but the slideviewer div is positioned to far to the right. In IE8, the betterTooltip does not display at all when hovering above the image.

I've looked at pngfixes and tried to implement the ie8.js pngfix to see if that was the problem, but the betterTooltip still doesn't display in IE. Am I missing something in my css?

The betterTooltip works just fine in IE when you visit the tutorial demo site: http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/234_tooltip/Demo/index.html

Any ideas as to what I've done wrong for it not to work in IE8?

Thanks so much,

Kamili

Comment: Sorry, I know this doesn't relate to your question, but please, please don't resize images by specifying the image size in the img tag or css. If you want the image to be displayed smaller, create a smaller image. Not only will it load (much) faster but you'll actually know how it's going to render vs leaving it up to the browser.

Comment: I think it's an issue with positioning. It appears in Opera put it appears WAY off the page down past the bottom. This seems to be the case in IE as well. Have you modified how it calculates the top value in any way? **Edit** To see what I mean, hover over the image and press the "End" key.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the tooltip, the problem comes from your other script.

check the file js_random.js, it has an error at line one.

try to remove this function and see how IE react

```
 function newWindow() {
  document.getElementByClass('new').target = "_blank";
 }
```

There is no method called getElementByClass in javascript, it's getElementByClassName

Answer (score 0):

I think IE has problems with a js which has syntax error.

> Message: Syntax error
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 1
>   Code: 0 
>   URI: http://www.pearlofthewest.com/js/js_random.js

If you have a script in a separate js file, you won't need the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Drackir. I will scale down the images and remove those img attributes. I changed the `betterTooltip.js` file parameters that specify where to place the tooltip:

```
/* Position the tooltip relative to the class 
           associated with the tooltip                */
        setTip = function(top, left){
            var topOffset = tip.height();
            //var xTip = (left-30)+"px";
            //var yTip = (top-topOffset-60)+"px";
            var xTip = "55%";
            var yTip = "340%";
            tip.css({'top' : yTip, 'left' : xTip});
        }
```

I commented out the author's set positioning and put my own because it positions the bettertooltip relative to the element to which it attaches: I wanted it to display in one place regardless of the element above which a visitor hovers. I'll recheck the positioning again.

Thanks rucsi and runrunforest, I removed the link to the `js_random.js` file, since it was not needed.